# sql service broker expires or is shut off

Tags: sql-server, service, signalr, sqldependency, broker

We use SQL service broker to Enable query notification for our SignalR application. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-query-notifications

This weekend suddenly the SQL service broker was turned off. I dont have any clue how this happened. Is it possible that the service broker expires? What could have happened?

Comment: Do you mean Service Broker was disabled in the database? This may occur if the database was restored, re-attached, or SB explicitly disabled. The default trace will log these events.

Comment: I searched the logs and the only striking thing i see is :
 
At 23-02-2019 10:13:16 :
A worker process with process id of '7852' serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit.

at 23-02-2019 10:13:20 the broker was shut down.and the iis starts creating error messages : The SQL Server Service Broker for the current database is not enabled, and as a result query notifications are not supported.  Please enable the Service Broker for this database if you wish to use notifications.